# Get all the products from the buy request object in observer

Tags: product, event-observer

I have the following :

```
   $buyRequest = $observer->getEvent()->getBuyRequest();
   $products = $buyRequest->getAllItems();
      foreach ($products as $product) {
         $productqtty = $product->getQty();
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: which event you are using?

Comment: It is catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options  public function catalogProductTypePrepare($observer)
    {